# C preprocessors and order of operations

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm learning C, but I do not understand this:

```
#define square(x) x*x
a = square(2+3) //a = 11
```

When this is run, why does `a` end up being `11`?

Comment: Just as a piece of advice, this example shows one of the many reasons why you should avoid using macros in C until the day comes where you **really** know what you are doing. Of course when that day comes, you will know why to avoid them in detail...

Comment: @T.E.D.: Macros (and the preprocessor in general) are a tool like any other. This example doesn't show why you shouldn't use macros in general - it just shows one particular use case for which it's inappropriate to apply them. There are both good and bad uses of macros.

Comment: That said, there are of course more bad uses than good ones :)

Comment: please name the question better

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It expands to `2+3*2+3`, which is equivalent to `2+(3*2)+3`. Use parentheses to fix it:

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Now try it with `square(x++)` and you'll run into more problems (undefined behavior). Avoid doing this as a macro if you can.

Comment: The equivalent c++ function should be just as efficient as a macro (on modern compilers with optimizations turned up) and will not suffer from this problem.

Comment: @Martin: Correct, if the OP is using C++. Indications are it's probably C. I think C99 also has inline functions, and it appears they're an extension in GNU C. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function#Language_support

Answer (score 12):

`square(2+3)` expands to `2+3*2+3` which is equivalent to `2+(3*2)+3` [`*` has higher precedence than `+`]

On gcc you can use `-E` option to see what your preprocessor generates

```
C:\Users\SUPER USER>type a.c
#define square(x) x*x

int main()
{
   a = square(2+3); //a = 11
}

C:\Users\SUPER USER>gcc -E a.c
# 1 "a.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "a.c"


int main()
{
   a = 2+3*2+3;
}
```

Remedy

Try this

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Comment: +1 for not only finding the problem but also teaching the OP (and the rest of us) how to debug such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Because `2 + 3` is substituted literally in the expression `x * x`, it becomes `2 + 3 * 2 + 3`, and the `*` operator has a higher precedence so you don't get the expected result.

Always enclose macro arguments and the whole expression in parentheses to avoid this:

```
#define SQUARE(x) ((x) * (x))
```

Also note that any expression you pass will be evaluated twice, and that can be undesired if the expression has a side effect such as an assignment, or a function call. In these cases it is better to use an inline function.

Comment: Always enclose macros in parentheses, too. With your suggestion, `1.0/square(x)` would then be evaluated to `1.0/(2+3)*(2+3)`, thus `1.0` instead of `0.04`.

Comment: @Sam: point taken. Ironic, but I myself have said that a few months ago in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455307/weird-macro-definition-issue/4455354#4455354

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

think about what you get when the macro is expanded. The c preprocessor will expand this as

```
a = 2 + 3 * 2 + 3
```

You need to correctly define your macro. Always enclose the macro variable in parenthesis. This would give you the expected result.

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

The macro expansion would be this:

```
a = ((2 + 3) * (2 + 3))
```

Comment: Your advice is not "correctly defining" the macro. `1.0/square(x)` would be evaluated to `1.0/(2+3)*(2+3)`, thus `1.0` instead of `0.04`.

Comment: I fixed the incorrectly defined macro. Added another set of enclosing parenthesis.