# Difference between !(variable) and (!variable)

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

In either C or C++, is there a conclusive difference between using `!(variable)` and `(!variable)` in an `if-statement`, such as:

`if (!(variable)) { .. // do something }`

or

`if (!variable && !(variable2)) { .. // do something }`

such that one version delivers a different result over the other?

Comment: Unmatched parens in the first code sample.  Normally this wouldn't be a big deal, but since your question is about parens or lack thereof, it's rather more important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way it would make a difference is if the variable is an expression, then its a matter of operator precedence. Otherwise `&&` has lower precedence than `!`

Comment: @Benoit, thanks for the contribution. I usually avoid macros so it slipped my mind.

Comment: It'd be better to put the parentheses in the macro itself, or best to avoid using a macro altogether. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807090/c-preprocessor-question/5807109#5807109

Answer (score 8):

Its all about order of operation.  Using !(variable) will evaluation all conditions inside of the parenthesis then do the ! (or NOT) to determine whether to enter the if statement where-as (!variable will do the NOT specifically on the variable itself.

So in the situations:

```
!(true && false) = true
!(true && true) = false
(!true && !false) = false
(!true && true) = false
!(true && !false) = false
```

...and so on

Hope this helped.

Comment: Note (as an aside): !(A && B) => (!A || !B)

Comment: @Martin gotta love De Morgan's law.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between

```
!(variable)
```

and

```
(!variable)
```

but if you are using operators that has different precedence you will have a difference. For example, if you write

```
!(varible1 && variable2)
```

is not the same as

```
!varible1 && variable2
```

because the NOT will be applid to the whole operation in the first case and only to `varible1` in the second case.

May be you are getting a problem with the evaluation, C has lazy evaluation, so when the execution detects that boolean evaluation has a result, it doesn't try the other values. So, now consider instead of variables you have functions.

```
int foo() { printf("foo\n"); return 1; }
int bar() { printf("bar\n"); return 0; }
```

If you write

```
if (foo() && bar()) { ... }
```

you will get

```
foo
bar
```

but if you write

```
if (bar() && foo()) { ... }
```

you will only get

```
bar
```

because the evaluation will be false, doesn't matter the result of `foo`

Answer (score 1):

No, in your example the first one (although the parens are unbalanced :)) behaves exactly like it would if there were no parentheses, and the second behaves the same way. You can even do this

```
if ((!((((variable)))))) { ... }
```

But don't :)

Answer (score 1):

They should never evaluate to different things.  Parentheses used this way are really for grouping operations, but in this case, you're not grouping any operations, just the expression itself.

So `!(x)` is just a pedantic way of writing `!x`

Now, if you had an operation inside the parentheses, that's where the differences start.