# Why is the result of this 62?

Tags: c++, c, operators

The only thing that passed to my mind was, MULT((3+2)(5*4))= 100 not 62? Can someone explain this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ADD(x1, y1) x1 + y1
#define MULT(x1,y1) x1 * y1


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g;
    a=2;
    b=3;
    c=4;
    d=5;
    e= MULT(ADD(a,b),MULT(c,d));
    printf("the value of e is: %d\n", e);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Macros are text substitution. Substitute it yourself and work it out.

Comment: Reason #54899 why macros are terrible in C++. This is why most macros have an absurd amount of parenthesis.

Comment: This is why macros are normally liberally sprinkled with parentheses.

Comment: @tenfour There's no C++ in there (except in the tags, which rarely means much).

Comment: Same answer as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5807090/10077

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Macros are awesome.  Programmers suck.  (Oh and this is like the poster child example for the macro haters).  And this is a C question, not C++.  (Hint, stdio.h instead of iostream)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When the macros are expanded, this:

```
MULT(ADD(a,b),MULT(c,d))
```

becomes:

```
a + b * c * d
```

which, replacing the variables with their values, is equivalent to:

```
2 + 3 * 4 * 5
```

and the value of this expression, evaluated according to the precedence rules, is 62, because multiplication has higher precedence than addition.

Don't use macros for this purpose:  use functions.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to lack of `()`s, you end up with:

```
e = a + b * c * d;
```

because:

```
MULT(ADD(a,b),MULT(c,d)) -> MULT(a + b,c * d) -> a + b * c * d
```

So,

```
e = 2 + 3 * 4 * 5 = 2 + 60 = 62
```

Answer (score 3):

Avoid macros in C++

Your problem will be solved by doing this :

```
#define ADD(x1, y1) ((x1) + (y1))
#define MULT(x1,y1) ((x1) * (y1))
```

But don't do it.

Instead use functions  (inline functions if necessary ).

```
int ADD(int x1, int y1) {
    return x1+y1;
}
```

Comment: Well... Actually not... The definitions should have even more paranthesis: `#define MULT(x1, y1) ((x1) * ((y1))`... Try `MULT(2 + 3, 4 + 5)`...

Comment: Not sure why you need (x1), but I may be missing something.  (EDIT : you are right - I see the case where it will break). Anyways, for his stated usecase (x1+y1) is enough. Ideally he should be using functions.

Comment: `MULT(2 + 3, 4 + 5) => (2 + 3 * 4 + 5) => (2 + 12 + 5) = 19`... Not the expected 45...

Comment: Yes.. that should be a very common case.. changing my answer.

Comment: For simple adds and multiply, the preprocessor can do the work instead of forcing it on the compiler.  (Your compiler may be able to work this out at compile time but not without optimizations turned on.)  As a general rule, yes write a function.  But there may be cases (especially in C) where you want the preprocessor to do the work.  Also, as a general rule, you want every macro argument to be surrounded with parenthesis (also use mangled arguments by prefixing and postfixing with _ to avoid namespace issues), and you want every "function-like" macro to have enclosing parens.

Comment: @Josh I may be missing something, but how about simply using `a + b` instead of an `ADD(a, b)` macro or an `add(a, b)` function? :)

Comment: @Chip: The rule for macros is (or should be): put parens around any use of a macro argument and around the entire macro.  Go against this rule only when the macro *requires* you to omit the parens, and when you can explain why the parens must be omitted. In particular, this rule means that statements such as "Not sure why you need (x1)..." should not considered evidence that you can skip the parens.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for the comments. Makes sense. I tend to avoid macros as much as possible.

Comment: @FredOverflow the OP obviously wants an ADD macro or function.  Also, I've seen this often when adding offsets to base addresses where the action of adding is of secondary importance to what the programmer wants which is the resultant address. e.g. ADDRESSOF(base_addr, magic_offset).  You can get the same result by just using a +, but its not as obvious as that you are computing the "address of" something.  Plus, with C writing + doesn't let you change it (no level of abstraction).